# node-exporter doesn't export node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes metric

Tags: linux, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have installed latest node-exporter on machine with Linux Mint 17 (kernel 3.13).
There is just one problem - I don't get `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes metric`.
I tried `sysctl kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1`, but this doesn't help. Other memory metrics like `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` are being shown.

What may be the reason and how to export available memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reddit' user **paulfantom** answer:

> Blockquote
> Kernel 3.13 doesn't expose `MemAvailable` information in /proc/meminfo as it was introduced in 3.14. That's why you cannot see it in node_exporter.

[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PrometheusMonitoring/comments/hr1fmh/nodeexporter_no_node_memory_memavailable_bytes/)